# Is it possible for a trigger to update a row in a table using a value that was deleted?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a trigger which is updating a column in a different table after the row is inserted:

```
mysql>delimiter $$

mysql> create trigger status

 after insert on table2

 FOR EACH ROW 

 BEGIN update

 table1 inner join table2

 ON table1.id=table2.id 

 set table1.state=0 ;
```

Now I want to reset the `table1.state=1` whenever the same value gets deleted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right, what you want is an `after delete trigger`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ad_foo AFTER DELETE on foo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  update table1 SET table1.state=1 WHERE id=OLD.id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Example with just the insert: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/974b4/1

Example with insert and delete: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bf72/1

Comment: thanks sir !! its working !!

but i'm unable to figure out yet that what makes the difference if i do it 'before delete'...

Comment: if you do 'before delete' and the delete fails for some reason, you're left with the `state=1` and the row still existing